# why is prepared statement in mysql running twice in ajax call?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am creating a web application made a file user.php which create a database connection and perform database operation.It is executing fine when the function for database manipulation is called.The problem arises when it is called from ajax.After the ajax call it inserts two identical rows in a database.I tried everything on google but could not understand the exact problem

user.php

```
function connectForCreatingAccount($username,$email,$password,$usertype)
{
    $servername = "localhost";
    $user= "root";
    $pass = "ghost";
    $dbname = "project";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $user, $pass, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

 // echo $username.$password.$email.$usertype; 
$verify = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `email` = ? ");
if($verify)
{
    $verify->bind_param("s",$email);
    $verify->execute() or die($conn->error);
    $result = $verify->get_result();
   // echo $result->num_rows;
    if($result->num_rows > 0)
    {

        $conn->close(); 
        return "EMAIL_ALREADY_EXISTS";
    }
}

$date=date("Y-m-d H-m-s");
$notes="";    
//echo $date;
$last_login=$date;
$register_login=$date;    
$pre_stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `user`
   ( `name`, `password`,`email`,  `usertype`, `register_date`, `last_login`, `notes`) 
   VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$pass_hash = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_BCRYPT,["cost"=>8]);

if($pre_stmt)
{
     $pre_stmt->bind_param("sssssss",$username,$pass_hash,$email,$usertype
     ,$last_login,$register_login,$notes);
    $result = $pre_stmt->execute() or die($conn->error);
    if($result)
        return $conn->insert_id;
    else
        return "SOME_ERROR";
}else
{
    return "SOME_ERROR";
}
  $conn->close();  
}
```

ajax call from other javascript file

```
 $.ajax({
    url : DOMAIN+"/includes/process.php",
   method : "POST",           
   data : temp,
   success : function(data)
     {
     if (data == "EMAIL_ALREADY_EXISTS") {
       alert("You have already registered");
      } else if(data == "SOME_ERROR"){
        alert("Something Wrong");
      }else {
        //alert(data);
        window.location.href  = encodeURI(DOMAIN+"/index.php?msg=you are registered");
      }
    }
 });
```

process.php which is calling the function from user.php

```
include_once("user.php");
// for registration

    if(isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["email"]))   //
    {
        //echo $_POST["name"];
        //echo $_POST["email"];

        $result = connectForCreatingAccount($_POST["name"],$_POST["email"]
          ,$_POST["password"],$_POST["usertype"]);

        echo $result;
    }
```

main.jss containing ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var DOMAIN = "http://localhost/project/";
  $("#registration_form").on("submit",function(e){
  // body...

  var statusN = false;
  var statusE = false;
  var statusP = false;
  var statusC = false;
  var statusT = false;
  // alert("hello");
  var name = $("#name");
  var email = $("#email")
  var password = $("#pwd");
  var cpassword = $("#cpwd");
  var usertype = $("#usertype");
  var n_patt = new RegExp(/^[A-Za-z ]+$/);
  var e_patt = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/);
  // alert("hello");
  if(name.val() == "" ||!n_patt.test(name.val()) ||name.val().length < 6)
    {
      name.addClass("border-danger");
      $("#n_error").html("<span class='text-danger'>
            Please Enter the Name and it has minimum 6 characters 
            and contains only alphabets</span>");
       statusN = false;
      }else
      {

        name.removeClass("border-danger");
        $("#n_error").html("");
        statusN = true;

       }    

       if(!e_patt.test(email.val()))
       {
         email.addClass("border-danger");
         $("#e_error").html("<span class='text-danger'>
               Please Enter the correct email format</span>");
         statusE = false;
       }else
       {

         email.removeClass("border-danger");
         $("#e_error").html("");
         statusE = true;
        }

      if(password.val() == "" || password.val().length < 9)
      {
        password.addClass("border-danger");
        $("#p_error").html("<span class='text-danger'>
             password length is greater than 9</span>");
        statusP = false;
      }else
      {

        password.removeClass("border-danger");
        $("#p_error").html("");
        statusP = true;

       }        

       if(cpassword.val() == "" || cpassword.val().length < 9)
       {
         cpassword.addClass("border-danger");
         $("#cp_error").html("<span class='text-danger'>
              password length is greater than 9</span>");
         statusC = false;
       }else
       {

         cpassword.removeClass("border-danger");
         $("#cp_error").html("");
         statusC = true;

       }     


       if(usertype.val() == "" )
         {
           usertype.addClass("border-danger");
           $("#t_error").html("<span class='text-danger'>select a user type</span>");
           statusT = false;
         } else
         {

           usertype.removeClass("border-danger");
           $("#t_error").html("");
           statusT = true;

          }    

          if((password.val() == cpassword.val()) && statusN == true 
              && statusE == true && statusP == true && statusC == true && statusT == true)
          {
            var temp = $("#registration_form").serialize();

            $.ajax({

            url : DOMAIN+"/includes/process.php",
            method : "POST",                        
            data : temp,
            success : function(data)
                 {
            if (data == "EMAIL_ALREADY_EXISTS") {
              alert("You have already registered");

            } else if(data == "SOME_ERROR"){
              alert("Something Wrong");
            }else
            {
                //alert(data);
                window.location.href  = encodeURI(DOMAIN+"/index.php?msg=you are registered");
             }
          }

        });


      }else
      {
        cpassword.addClass("border-danger");
        $("#cp_error").html("<span class='text-danger'>password does not match</span>");
        status = true;
      } 
      e.preventDefault();      
     })
```

Comment: Your file is `user.php`, but in your ajax settings, url is `includes/process.php`

Comment: Have you forgotten `e.preventDefault()` on the form or you attached the same event handler twice?

Comment: Possible as well is connectForCreatingAccount() being called twice somewhere.

Comment: process.php is calling a function from user.php

Comment: I have callied e.preventDefault() after  ajax call

Comment: Pls post code of process.php and full code of the html and ajax file

Comment: I have posted the code of process.php

Comment: Of file where the ajax call resides?